# I need to insert .csv file (stripping out a certain characters from a column) into a Table in SSMS, using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, ssms, bulk, openrowset

I have the following .csv file:

I need to import this file into the table (MyTable) with the same fields-  in SSMS, using T-SQL statements.

My import result should also remove any characters before '-' sign, in the ID column

[image]

So, I expect the following in the SSMS table:

[image]

Trying the following code, but I am not familiar with the correct syntax.
It's incorrect and I don't know the correct way of writing this.
Also, not sure if this even possible to achieve:

```
      INSERT INTO myTable1 ([Name], [ID])

      SELECT 
            (Text1.[Name], 
             RIGHT(Text1.[ID]), LEN(Text1.[ID]) - Charindex('-', Text1.[ID]))
    
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\$_Data\OQ\Text1.csv', SINGLE_BLOB) AS ttt;
```

`RIGHT(Text1.[ID]), LEN(Text1.[ID]) - Charindex('-', Text1.[ID]))` - that's where I am stripping out  everything before '-', including this character. It works in a regular SELECT OR JOIN statement
But not here

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use OPENROWSET with a format file describing the columns in your CSV file. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) an xml format file could look like this for your sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR=";" MAX_LENGTH="7"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
    </RECORD>
    <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ID" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
    </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Then, use it in the openrowset statement:

```
SELECT 
     Name
    ,[ID]
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK N'path-to\test.csv',
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FORMATFILE = N'path-to\test-csv.xml'
) AS ttt;
```

And at last your stripping code seems to have bad syntax - RIGHT expects two arguments:

```
RIGHT([ID], LEN([ID]) - Charindex('-', [ID])) AS STRIPPED_ID
```